# Can I take the same Daily Spell twice?

Tags: 13th-age

13th Age uses a 4-E'ish system of Daily, Encounter, Rechargable, and At-Will powers for it's abilities. However, Spells are treated a little oddly compared to, say, Class Talents in that, well, a spell caster tends to know a lot more of them, and can freely change them up at a Full Heal Up (i.e. between 'days'.)

What's not made clear anywhere in the rules however, is whether I can use two of my 6 or so spells known to take the same limited use (let's say Daily for simplicities sake) spell twice, so I can use it more times. Is this possible? Or must I take 6 separate and distinct spells?

<sub>(The only *explicit* reference I can find to something like this is that *Utility Spell* can be taken multiple times to grant multiple uses of it's various permutations. Utility Spell *is* a daily, but it behaves strangely in a dozen other ways too.)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, Not By Default

There is a Wizard Class Talent called **High Arcana** which, if taken, can grant you the ability you desire.  From page 149:

> Unlike other spellcasters, who can only choose a specific spell once, when you pick your spells, you can choose any **daily** wizard spell twice.

Given the existence of this Class Talent, and some inference from the text of the *utility spell* description, you cannot by default take the same **daily** spell twice.

### On The *Utility Spell*

The section of the rules about the *Utility Spell* can be found on page 150 of the **13th Age** Core Rulebook.

The way the *utility spell* works is that, in place of a spell slot, you can memorize the *utility spell*, allowing you to use any of the daily spells that are part of the *utility spell* at the level you memorized it.  At 1st level, the *utility spell* gives you access to three different spells.  It is important to note that all *utility spells* are **daily**, and you can only use one of them per full heal-up ("day"), not all three:

> For example, if you memorize the utility spell slot at 3rd level, you can cast one of the following six spells at 3rd level as a standard action: *disguise self*, *feather fall*, *hold portal*, *levitate*, *message*, or *speak with item*.  You don't have to decide ahead of time which *utility spell* you will cast.  You can also memorize the *utility spell* multiple times by giving up a spell slot for each use.

If you memorize the *utility spell* multiple times by giving up a spell slot for each instance, you can use that many of the *utility spells* per day, but still only once per spell.  There are also a couple of feats associated with the *utility spell*:

> ***Adventurer Feat***: Each *utility spell* you take lets you cast two spells from the available options instead of one.

You cannot cast the same **daily** spell from the *utility spells* list multiple times in a day, but rather this gives you the ability to cast two *different* *utility spells* in a given day, as opposed to just one.  This is the same effect as memorizing the *utility spell* twice in place of two spell slots.  This effect stacks, so if you have the *Utility Spell* ***Adventurer Feat***, and memorize the *utility spell* twice in exchange for two spell slots, then you can cast **four** different *utility spells* in a day, but still only once per day for each of them.

Comment: Aha! I had missed the High Arcana talent; yup, that clarifies things explicitly and perfectly.